# how to draw a third hamonic injection to the reference signal

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

I'm a newbie in using TIKZ latex package for drawing plots.
I'd like to draw a third harmonic injection plot similar to the attached photo.
Nb, Theta(1)= pi/3......Theta (2)= 2*pi/3

Here's the draft code (my initial try), but, clearly it not fit the desired plot

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}

\hspace*{\fill}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[width=4in, axis equal image,
          xmin=0, xmax=3,
          ymin=-1.5, ymax=1.5,
          axis lines=center,
          %enlargelimits,
          %axis line style={shorten >=-0.25cm,shorten <=-0.25cm,latex-latex},
          ticklabel style={fill=white},
          extra x ticks={0},
          xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
          clip=false,]

\addplot[domain=0:2.5,mark=none,samples=200] {abs(sin(deg(pi*x)))} node[fill=white, right]{$y=\vert\sin(\ x)\vert$};

\addplot[domain=0:2.5,mark=none,draw=red,samples=200] {abs(0.5*sin(deg(pi*3*x)))} node[fill=white, right]{$y=\vert\ 0.5* sin(\ 3 * x)\vert$};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Third harmonic injection]
Please help

Comment: Why do you use `abs` where there  is no absolute function needed? Or am I mistaken? Could you elaborate on what you're trying to achieve? Your graph seems pretty OK to me.

Comment: @SebGlav, yes you're right. The abs is a mistake, but the photo is blured and just modified in photoshop and i didn't like the quality of the image. I'd like to re-draw it using tikz pakage for better quality

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### EDIT

Added Theta 1 and Theta 2 as requested.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}

\hspace*{\fill}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[width=4in, axis equal image,
          xmin=0, xmax=3,
          ymin=-1.5, ymax=1.5,
          axis lines=center,
          %enlargelimits,
          %axis line style={shorten >=-0.25cm,shorten <=-0.25cm,latex-latex},
          ticklabel style={fill=white},
          %extra x ticks={0},
          xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
          clip=false,]

\addplot[domain=0:2.5,mark=none,draw=blue,samples=200] {sin(deg(pi*x))} node[blue, right]{$y=\sin x$};

\addplot[domain=0:2.5,mark=none,draw=red,samples=200] {0.25*sin(deg(pi*3*x))} node[red,right,yshift=-3pt]{$y= 0.25 \sin 3x$};

\addplot[domain=0:2.5,mark=none,draw=green!50!black,samples=200] {sin(deg(pi*x))+0.25*sin(deg(pi*3*x))} node[green!50!black, right]{Sum};

\newcommand{\uplim}{0.895}
\newcommand{\ta}{0.27}
\draw (axis cs:0,1) -- (axis cs:1.5,1);
\draw (axis cs:0,\uplim) -- (axis cs:1.5,\uplim);
\draw[densely dashed] (axis cs:\ta,\uplim) -- (axis cs:\ta,0) node[below]{$\theta_1$};
\draw[densely dashed] (axis cs:1-\ta,\uplim) -- (axis cs:1-\ta,0) node[below]{$\theta_2$};


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: third harmonic]

Comment: Good try @SebGlav, please, could you add theta (1)=pi/3 and theta (2)=2*pi/3 as mentioned in the attached figure ?

Comment: Done. You'll have to use `\draw (axis cs: <coord>)` to access to axes coordinates and draw with them, on pgfplots. You get the point, even if you have to change values.

Comment: And btw, your ticks are strange since they don't mention `pi` but only the factor. Maybe you should change this.

Comment: You're right @SebGlav, the x ticks should be in radian 0.....pi....2*pi   etc